# Replace all UpperLetters in a string with a new String

Tags: java, string

I have a string in the format of UserTable. I want the output as user_table. Basically replace all the uppercase letters with "_" and letter. like `R=_R`.

i have this code and it works fine.

```
public static String getTableName(String clazz){
        String name = (clazz.charAt(0)+"").toLowerCase();
        for(int itr=1;itr<clazz.length();itr++){
            char ch = clazz.charAt(itr);
            if(ch >=97 && ch <=122)
                name += ch;
            else
                name += ("_"+ ch).toLowerCase() ;

        }
        return name;
    }
```

I just want if this can be done in a neater way.

Comment: This sounds like a job for regexes

Comment: Hmmm I don't think this is a valid question for SO. But yes, it can be done in a neater way.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, either fix your example to `R=_r` or your code, because it would return the letter as lowercase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suggestion: Use a regular expression, which prepends uppercase characters with an underscore (not at the beginning though, therefore negative look behind `(?!^)`), transform result to lowercase:

```
String input = "UserTable";
String result = input.replaceAll("(?!^)([A-Z])", "_$1").toLowerCase();
System.out.println(result); // user_table
```

Comment: OP does not want the entire result toLowerCase, he specify he wants R=_R

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard This specification is wrong. Look at his code. Since he said it works fine, he created a contradiction :D. OPs code would also produce the result "user_table".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Looking at his example, he wants the result to be lowercase. If not, simply remove the `.toLowerCase()` part.

Comment: Thanks i was looking something like this.. didnt know how to use $1. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringBuilder` to achieve this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String input = "UserTable";

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
  char ch = input.charAt(i);

  if (i > 0 && Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
    builder.append('_');
  }

  builder.append(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
}

String result = builder.toString();
```